# Example of Failure of Hoeffding's Inequality for Empirical Risk Minimization

Tags: machine-learning, probability, supervised-learning, high-dimensional

I am studying [*Introduction to Statistical Learning Theory* by Bousquet, Boucheron and Lugosi](http://www.econ.upf.edu/%7Elugosi/mlss_slt.pdf). On pages 183 through 185 it considers the applicability of Hoeffding's Inequality to Empirical Risk Minimization (ERM). The setting is as follows.

Let $Z_1,...,Z_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. samples drawn from a distribution. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of functions. For every $f\in\mathcal{F}$, define its *risk* $R(f)$ and *empirical risk* $R_n(f)$ by
$$
R(f)=\mathbb{E}f(Z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
R_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(Z_i).
$$
Let $f^*\in\mathcal{F}$ be the minimizer of $R(f)$ over all $f\in\mathcal{F}$, and $f_n\in\mathcal{F}$ the minimizer of $R_n(f)$ over all $f\in\mathcal{F}$.

For simplicity assume that $f(z)\in[0,1]$ for all $z$. Hoeffding's Inequality says that for all $\delta\in(0,1]$, for a fixed $f\in\mathcal{F}$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|R(f)-R_n(f)\right|\le\sqrt{\frac{\log(2/\delta)}{2n}}\right)\ge 1-\delta.
$$
However, this result does not say anything about $|R(f_n)-R_n(f_n)|$ because $f_n$ is random.

**My question:** Is there any concrete example showing that $|R(f_n)-R_n(f_n)|$ does not obey the bound $\sqrt{\log(2/\delta)/(2n)}$ with probability $1-\delta$?

Comment: >> "Let $f^*\in\mathcal{F}$ be the minimizer of $R(f)$ over all $f\in\mathcal{F}$, and $f_n\in\mathcal{F}$ the minimizer of $R(f)$ over all $f\in\mathcal{F}$."

Is $f_n$ a minimizer of $R_n(f)$? Otherwise, it's the same as $f^*$.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't so much finding an example -- the result will typically fail for some $n$ and $\delta$ when ${\cal F}$ has more than one entry -- as doing the calculations when most of the available tools are designed to give upper bounds.

Here's a ridiculously extreme version: for every finite set of points $S$ in $\mathbb R$ define a function $f_S(z)$ that is 0 if $z\in S$ and 1 otherwise. Let $\cal F$ be the set of such functions. Then $f_n$ will be a function that is 0 at every observed point, giving $R_n(f_n)=0$ a.s.

On the other hand, since all finite sets have measure zero, for any fixed $f_S$ we will observe no points in $S$ (a.s.) and have $f(Z_i)=1$ a.s and so $R(f)=1$.

This does illustrate what causes the problem: overfitting. When ${\cal F}$ has multiple competing $f$s, the one that gets chosen as $f_n$ will typically have  $R_n(f_n)<R(f_n)$, because that's how it got chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example! In the last formula do you mean $R_n(f_n)<R_n(f)$? Also, it seems that in this example every $f\in\mathcal{F}$ minimizes $R(f)$.

Comment: Every $f$ has $R(f)=1$, so in  that sense every $f$ minimises $R(f)$, but not $R_n(f)$. I assumed you meant $f_n$ minimised $R_n$, because otherwise $f_n$ and $f^*$ are defined identically.